# MySQL Query Optimization for running total query - How can I reduce query exectuion time?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, query-tuning

**Problem**

I have a query that I pasted below.  The problem I face is how can I trim the latency to under the current time of about 10 seconds.

```
set@ csum = 0;
SELECT Date_format(assigneddate, '%b %d %Y') AS assigneddate, (@csum: = @csum + numactionitems) AS totalactionitems
FROM(
    SELECT assigneddate,
    Sum(numactionitems) AS numactionitems FROM(
        SELECT assigneddate,
        Count( * ) AS numactionitems FROM(
            SELECT *
            FROM(
                SELECT actionitemtitle,
                actionitemstatement,
                altownerid,
                approvalstatement,
                assigneddate,
                assignorid,
                closeddate,
                closurecriteria,
                closurestatement,
                criticality,
                duedate,
                ecd,
                notes,
                ownerid,
                Concat(lastname, ', ', firstname) AS owner,
                cnames2.categoryvalue AS `team`,
                cnames2.categorynameid AS `teamid`,
                cnames3.categoryvalue AS `department`,
                cnames3.categorynameid AS `departmentid`,
                cnames4.categoryvalue AS `source`,
                cnames4.categorynameid AS `sourceid`,
                cnames5.categoryvalue AS `project_phase`,
                cnames5.categorynameid AS `project_phaseid`,
                ac1.actionitemid FROM actionitemcategories AS ac1 INNER JOIN actionitems AS a INNER JOIN users AS u INNER JOIN(
                    SELECT actionitemid AS a2id,
                    categorynameid AS c2 FROM actionitemcategories WHERE categoryid = 195) AS ac2 INNER JOIN categorynames AS cnames2 ON cnames2.categorynameid = ac2.c2 AND ac1.categoryid = 195 AND a.actionitemid = ac2.a2id AND ac1.actionitemid = a.actionitemid AND a.ownerid = u.userid INNER JOIN(
                    SELECT actionitemid AS a3id,
                    categorynameid AS c3 FROM actionitemcategories WHERE categoryid = 200) AS ac3 INNER JOIN categorynames AS cnames3 ON cnames3.categorynameid = ac3.c3 AND ac2.a2id = ac3.a3id INNER JOIN(
                    SELECT actionitemid AS a4id,
                    categorynameid AS c4 FROM actionitemcategories WHERE categoryid = 202) AS ac4 INNER JOIN categorynames AS cnames4 ON cnames4.categorynameid = ac4.c4 AND ac3.a3id = ac4.a4id INNER JOIN(
                    SELECT actionitemid AS a5id,
                    categorynameid AS c5 FROM actionitemcategories WHERE categoryid = 203) AS ac5 INNER JOIN categorynames AS cnames5 ON cnames5.categorynameid = ac5.c5 AND ac4.a4id = ac5.a5id) s WHERE 1 = 1) f GROUP BY assigneddate UNION ALL(
            SELECT a.date AS assigneddate,
            0 AS numactionitems FROM(
                SELECT '2015-03-05' + INTERVAL(a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) day AS date FROM(
                    SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a CROSS JOIN(
                    SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b CROSS JOIN(
                    SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c) a) ORDER BY assigneddate ASC) t GROUP BY assigneddate LIMIT 282) t
WHERE assigneddate != '0000-00-00'
```

**Purpose of Query**

The purpose of this query is to get all records that contain date values and to collect the running count of all records that fall on a certain date.    **Date values are computed within the sqlfiddle below.**  It's final purpose is to be displayed in a graph that takes the running total as a line graph.  It will be counting upwards so it is a growing graph.

The graph I am displaying it in is called a build-up graph of all my records (action items with date values).

**Description of Issue**

My problem is that I am getting the results of the query in at least 10 seconds.

**Question**

How can I accelerate and reduce the latency of the query so that I will not stall the loading of my graph?

**Complete Schema and portion of my above query that Runs Successfully**

(I am having difficulty getting the main query to run at all on sqlfiddle, though I can run it from my own machine).

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/865ee/11

Any help or suggestions would be tremendously appreciated!

EDIT

ADDED Sample Screenshot of my Categories Interface

Category (First Table) has a field called categoryname which assumes one of 4 values can be expanded or deleted which is - Team, Department, Source, Project_Phase.

CategoryName (Second Table) has a field called categoryvalue which is the actual allowed value for each category (First Table)

Example - Team 1, Team 2, Team 3 are categoryvalues within categoryname and corresponding the category of Team.

Category

[image: Categories]

Comment: The 4 inner joins (for categorynames) are dynamically generated tables that contains variable number of categories.  So I am converting rows and making them columns.  The purpose of this is to support dynamic "categories" to serve as columns as opposed to a fixed amount of columns.   Really I use this in a filter to select values for dynamic category values.

Comment: Can you reformat the question so the query isn't indented so far?

Comment: Please see above.  Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: It's just as hard to read in the fiddle

Comment: Please let me know if the formats are more clear.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Start by making that table of dates a permanent table, not a subquery.

This construct performs very poorly, and can usually be turned into `JOINs` without subqueries:

```
JOIN ( SELECT ... )
JOIN ( SELECT ... )
```

This is because there is no index on the subqueries, so full scans are needed.

Provide `EXPLAIN` for the entire query.

**Addenda**

A `PRIMARY KEY` is a key; don't add another key with the same column(s).

EAV schema leads to complexity and sluggishness that you are encountering.

Don't use `TINYTEXT`; it slows down tmp tables in complex queries; use `VARCHAR(255)`.  Don't use `VARCHAR(255)`, use `VARCHAR` with a realistic limit.

Why do you need both `categories` and `categorynames`?

Comment: Thank you for the information.  Explain of query shown here  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/865ee/14